# How to create a program that show a^b is less than or more than e^c

Tags: c, math

i wanna ask some question. How to make a program that requires you to show is `a^b > e^c` ?(e is euler constant) for example : when I input

```
Input : 7 1 3
Output : >
```

Because `7^1 is 7 and e^3 is 20.0855` therefore `7 < 20.085`

I tried this code but it cant take for `a = 1000000, b = 1000000, c = 1000000` where it is `1000000^1000000 (sign) e^1000000`

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int testcase;
    double a,b,c,e;
    scanf("%d",&testcase); getchar();

    for(int i = 1; i <= testcase; i++){
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&a,&b,&c); getchar();
        double normalSquare = 0;
        double eSquare = 0;
        normalSquare = pow(a,b);
        eSquare = exp(c); //  Ini e^x
        printf("Normal Square : %lf\n",normalSquare);
        printf("eSquare : %lf \n",eSquare);
        if(normalSquare > eSquare){
            printf("Case #%d: >\n", i);
        } else {
            printf("Case #%d: <\n",i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `1000000^1000000` is a ***very*** large number, much larger than a `double` can handle. If you want to use such large numbers you need ti implement the algorithms yourself, or (which I recommend) find a library that can handle arbitrarily large numbers (like [this one](https://gmplib.org)).

Comment: Do you know how big 1,000,000 ^ 1,000,000 is?  And do you know what the largest value for a `double` is?

Comment: Probably want to use logarithms. Assuming a > 0 then a^b > e^c if and only if b*log(a) > c where log is the natural logarithm.

Comment: Hint: natural logs will allow you to do this with some pretty hefty numbers and exponents. You don't want `exp` ; you want `log` and some basic math involving natural log properties.

Comment: " it cant take"... Please edit your question (and especially its title) to say why you say that.

Answer (score 5):

Rearrange the formula to

```
b * log(a) > c * log(e)
```

and `log(e)` is 1 (assuming natural logarithms which is also the base of the C standard library `log` function), so this simplifies further to

```
b * log(a) > c
```

At least then you will not be overflowing the `double`, which is what is happening to you. "Working in log space" is something that, as a numerical programmer, you'll have to get used to.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the trick works because `log` is a monotonic function, and thus, it preserves order.